# Require one of two checkboxes = True, based on Record Type

Tags: validation-rule, record-type, checkbox

Require one of two checkboxes = True, based on Record Type
We have two checkboxes "Serviced" or "Not Serviced", in which one will be require to be 'true' in order to save AND Only 1 of the 2 checkboxes can be checked.

The rule will only apply to record types "Work Order 1" or "Work Order 2".

I have attempted it two ways, both pass syntax but do not present an error as they should:

```java
AND(
    $RecordType.Name = "Work Order 1",
    $RecordType.Name = "Work Order 2"
)
IF(
    (Not_Serviced__c , 1 , 0) + IF( Serviced__c, 1 , 0) < 1
)
)
```

---

```java
AND
(
    $RecordType.Name = "Work Order 1",
    $RecordType.Name = "Work Order 2",
    Not_Serviced__c, 
    Serviced__c
)
```

Comment: The first attempt should have ran into a syntax error or three.

Answer (score 2):

Your second attempt is close, but makes one big mistake.

A single field can only hold a single value, so something like `AND(field1 == value1, field1 == value2)` or `OR(field1 != value1, field1 != value2)` will *always return false*

- If you're checking a single field for equality to more than one value, you need to use `OR()`
- If you're checking a single field for *inequality* to more than one value, you need to use `AND()`

Also keep in mind that your validation formula needs to result in `true` for the validation rule to fire.

It can help to frame the formula in plain language first. In this case, I would explain it like so:

- When the record type is "1" or "2"
- And the `Serviced__c` checkbox is checked
- And the `Not_Serviced__c` checkbox is checked
- Then the data is invalid and we should complain

So in this formula, you will need to use both `OR()` and `AND()`

...of course, some alternatives here would be to

- Get rid of the second checkbox (having `Serviced__c` be unchecked is a wonderful indicator that it has *not been serviced*, making the second checkbox redundant)
- Make one of the two fields a formula field (checkbox type) where its value is the opposite of the checkbox field that isn't a formula

Either of those two approaches would mean that you don't need to write a validation rule at all (and why do you want to add more work onto your plate?)

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback Derek.

Comment: We started with just the one checkbox, now leadership has required the second checkbox due to service complexity, so I cannot get rid of the either checkbox.   Your second suggestion may be the way using a formula - I would make the a third field, a formula field that counts if one or both of the checkboxes are checked and then run the validation rule to error if it is not 1 (or if it is 0 or 2)...

Comment: @BLeahy In general, customers (external, or internal like leadership or other teams) should not decide _how_ to solve a problem. They should be limited to defining _what_ the issue is, and leave figuring out the "how" to you/your colleagues. People who don't work as Salesforce developers or admins do not know the complexity involved. If left to their own devices, your org will become a nightmare (redundant fields, conflicting validation rules, one team breaking something another team relied on, rules with exceptions upon exceptions, etc...)

Comment: This is now working successfully using this code:        And(
ISPICKVAL( Type,"Work Order 1"), ISPICKVAL( Type,"Work Order 2"), NOT(OR( Not_Serviced_c = true, Serviced__c = true))